# OData Destination in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, web-services, ssis, odata, etl

Integration Services (SSIS) supports reading data from **OData sources**. However, there is **no OData destination** component.

I cannot specify the OData webservice with an HTTP connection manager as web service task in SSIS (i.e. it does not support Windows Authentication).

Using Entity Framework/ASP.NET I think I could just write a post-deployment script. But is there a more straightforward way to update OData (if possible in SSIS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an `ODATA Destination` component created by Microsoft. You can find `ODATA Source` and create an `ODATA` connections only. *(In SQL Server 2014 you have to [install it from the feature pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-and-uninstall-odata-source-component?view=sql-server-2014), in 2016+ it is included)*.

On the other hand, there is some third party components that you can find in Visual Studio Marketplace:

- [OData SSIS Components](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/odata/ssis/)
- [SSIS Data Flow Source & Destination for OData](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.SSISDataFlowSourceDestinationforOData)

---

There was a feature request on [Visual Studio website](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17404165-support-odata-destination) to support `ODATA Destination`, and it was closed.